# Rails Nested Joins Activerecord with conditions

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to write a nested joins query with a condition.

The query I have right now is:

```ruby
Event.joins(:store => :retailer).where(store: {retailer: {id: 2}})
```

Which outputs the following SQL:

```
   SELECT "events".* FROM "events" INNER JOIN "stores" ON "stores"."id" = "events"."store_id" INNER JOIN "retailers" ON "retailers"."id" = "stores"."retailer_id" WHERE "store"."retailer_id" = '---
:id: 2
'
```

And also the following error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: store.retailer_id: SELECT "events".* FROM "events" INNER JOIN "stores" ON "stores"."id" = "events"."store_id" INNER JOIN "retailers" ON "retailers"."id" = "stores"."retailer_id" WHERE "store"."retailer_id" = '---
:id: 2
'
```

It's telling me there is no column store.retailer_id, however, I can run the following query and it will work just fine:

```
Event.first.store.retailer_id
  Event Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events"   ORDER BY "events"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Store Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "stores".* FROM "stores"  WHERE "stores"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 28958]]
=> 4
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Looks like you don't need nested joins here. Try to use something like

```
Event.joins(:store).where(stores: {retailer_id: 2})
```

Nested join should also work using `stores`

```
Event.joins(:store => :retailer).where(stores: {retailer: {id: 2}})
```

Comment: Awesome, I needed to use "stores" instead of "store".... Such an easy fix. Thank you dimuch!

Comment: Ditto @stytown - it has taken me DAYS to realise that even though I'm using a `:has_one` relationship, I need to pluralize the association name in the where clause. You just saved my hide.

Comment: Just a note that this becomes quite a bit uglier once you have namespaces on your tables:
    `Event.joins(:store).where("namespace_stores.retailer_id = ?", 2)`

Comment: This answer is still saving our hides 7 years later (or at least just saved mine). For all that I don't understand this pluralization convention, it's nice that Rails hasn't changed its mind back and forth in the years since.

Answer (score 6):

There is the simplest way instead of using curly brackets :

```
Event.joins(:store => :retailer).where('stores.retailer_id => ?', 2)
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to access the `retailers id` with the following syntax:

```
Event.joins(:store => :retailer).where('retailers.id' => 2)
```

ps. tested on Rails 5