# How can i find a model given a reverse lookup with rails ORM::ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have been breaking my head trying to do something simple but i can't. Im using rails version 4.2.6

The thing is that i have this three models with the next values.

```
Bet
   match_id
   #more values..

Match
   #values...

MatchResult
   match_id (One to one relation with match, that means i have a has_one...)
   #more values...
```

what im trying to do is something like this

```
Bet.where(:match => {:match_results => nil})
```

Also tried using Bet.joins() method but its not working, i saw and tried also something like this post, but i could not figure out a way.
[Rails Nested Joins Activerecord with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111426/rails-nested-joins-activerecord-with-conditions)

So basically i want to bring all Bets which have a Match which does not have any Match_result.match_id. If i get Match.first.match_result it does work and bring me one. Is there any way to bring them?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to join like this? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43588263/activemodel-search-by-association/43588738#43588738

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Bet.includes(match: :match_result).where(match_results: { id: nil })
```